# Is there a functon similar to DateDiff in MonetDB which can calculate number of weeks between two dates

Tags: monetdb

Consider two dates, "01-Jan-2011' & '01-Oct-2011'.
I wish to calculate number of weeks in between these dates.

I have tried the following:

```
select extract ( week from ( (current_date+ interval '5' day) - current_date ));
```

- It returns error " no such unary operator 'week(day_interval)'"

I am able to find number of days by using following :

```
select extract ( day from ( (current_date+ interval '5' day) - current_date ));
```

- the line above returns the output

Is there any way I can achieve the same?

Further, MonetDB considers week from Monday to Sunday(1-7). Is there any way this can be updated/ customised to Sunday to Saturday.

Thanks.

Comment: MonetDB doesn't support customising the starting day of the week yet.  But some new features in this area will be introduced this year.  I'll update the information after the release.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possibilities that I can think of:

```
select date '2011-10-01' - date '2011-01-01';
```

results in a INTERVAL DAY value, actually expressed in seconds of the difference, i.e. 23587200.000.  This you could divide by (7*24*60*60), i.e. the number of seconds in a week.  But it's still an INTERVAL type, not an INTEGER.

Another way is to first convert the date to integers: the number of seconds since "the epoch" (Jan 1, 1970):

```
select epoch_ms(date '2011-10-01');
```

This actually give milliseconds since the epoch, so an extra factor of 1000.

This result you can then manipulate to get what you want:

```
select (epoch_ms(date '2021-02-02') - epoch_ms(date '2020-12-31')) / (7*24*60*60*1000);
```

This results in a HUGEINT value (if you have 128 bit integers in your system, i.e. anything compiled with GCC or CLANG), so you can convert this to INTEGER:

```
select cast((epoch_ms(date '2011-10-01') - epoch_ms(date '2011-01-01')) / (7*24*60*60*1000) as integer);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sjoerd. I had tried the following to get the number of weeks :  
    select cast((sys.epoch(current_date + interval '3' day) - sys.epoch(current_date)) / (7*24*60*60) as integer);

But this doesn't handle the case where the difference between dates is less than 7 but belong to two different weeks.
Consider the case : date1 as '12-02-2021'( belongs to week 6) and date2 as '15-02-2021'( belongs to week 7)
If I execute the above query, it returns 0.
I need some way so that number of week gets calculated considering this aspect as well and in the above case should return 1 as output.